# mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in

Tags: php, html, mysql

Me aparece el siguiente error en esta linea de codigo:

```
if ($reg1=mysqli_fetch_array($reg))
```

Pero se que esos paremetros tienen que ver con lo siguiente:

```
    $reg = mysqli_prepare($conexv, "SELECT id FROM ventas WHERE sim = ?") or die ("Problemas en consulta".mysqli_error($conexv));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($reg, "i", $ingresarSim);
mysqli_stmt_execute($reg);
```

el codigo que tiene que ver con todo lo relacionado a lo que da error  es este por si les ayuda:

```
    mysqli_select_db($conexv,$db) or die("problemas base de datos");

$reg = mysqli_prepare($conexv, "SELECT id FROM ventas WHERE sim = ?") or die ("Problemas en consulta".mysqli_error($conexv));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($reg, "i", $ingresarSim);
mysqli_stmt_execute($reg);

if ($reg1=mysqli_fetch_array($reg))
{
    mysqli_query($conexv, "DELETE FROM sim WHERE SIM = $ingresarSim");
    echo "Datos Eliminados";
}
else {
    echo "Datos no han sido Eliminados";
}
```

Comment: Esa es con query, no estoy usando query, si recuerdas me dijiste que usara:
 mysqli_prepare

Comment: Lo revise entero y lo tengo todo bien, aun no encuentro el fallo

Comment: Exacto, eso mismo busco, el programa es para borrar un registro de una base de datos cuando sea igual a la de otra base de datos

Comment: Mmmm, me pudieras explicar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código podría quedar así.

Aquí he aplicado: usar consultas preparadas para dar seguridad al código. Pero implementando mejoras, como controlar el valor en sí devuelto por el `SELECT`.

Aquí tienes un código totalmente controlado, que te permitirá saber en todo momento lo que ha fallado y por qué ha fallado. He evitado poner en `$outPut` mensajes internos del manejador de BD, porque no es recomendable hacerlo, pero en fase de depuración, si tienes algún error, puedes agregarlo temporalmente a la salida para que te ayude revisar/corregir el código, aunque lo mejor es siempre recurrir a log de errores.

Aquí está el código, he puesto comentarios *in situ* sobre algunos aspectos. Si hay alguna duda me dices en comentarios:

```
<?php
/*
    En mysqli se puede evitar esto
      si pasas $db como 4º parámetro al crear $conexv
    Por otra parte, evitaremos el uso de die()
      usando una variable de control ($outPut)
      para todo el flujo del código
*/
if (mysqli_select_db($conexv,$db)) {
    /*
        Controlamos que no haya fallos preparando
    */
    if ($reg = mysqli_prepare($conexv, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ventas WHERE sim = ?")) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($reg, "i", $ingresarSim);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($reg);
        /*
            Es mejor usar mysqli_stmt_bind_result
               que no depende de ningún driver
               Aquí $mTotal será el valor encontrado en el COUNT(*)
        */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($reg, $mTotal);
        /*
            Verificamos si hay filas encontradas o no
        */
        if ($mTotal>0) {
            /*
                Verificamos que no hay error preparando la consulta DELETE
            */ 
            if ( $eliminado = mysqli_query($conexv, "DELETE FROM sim WHERE SIM = ?") ) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($eliminado, "i", $ingresarSim);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($eliminado);
                /*
                    Verificamos si realmente se borraron filas
                       en un DELETE pueden ocurrir errores 
                       en cuyo caso las filas afectadas será igual a -1
                       o no borrarse ninguna fila
                */
                $mDeleted=mysqli_affected_rows($conexv);
                if ( $mDeleted===-1 ) {
                    $outPut="Hubo un error ejecutando la consulta DELETE";
                } else {
                    $outPut="Filas borradas: $mDeleted";
                }
            } else {
                $outPut="Error preparando consulta DELETE";
            }
        } else {
            $outPut="No se encontraron filas";
        }
    } else {
        $outPut="Error preparando la consulta SELECT";  
    }
} else {
    $outPut="problemas base de datos";
}
/*
    Imprimimos la variable de control
*/
echo $outPut;
```

---

### PD

Como último consejo, te invitaría a usar el estilo orientado a objetos. En mysqli el estilo procedural es demasiado verboso, produciendo un código horrible para mi gusto. Me refiero a cosas como esta `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($reg, "i", $ingresarSim)`, son kilométricas, en estilo orientado a objetos quedaría así:  `$reg->bind_param("i", $ingresarSim);` Veámosla una debajo de otra para ver la diferencia:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($reg, "i", $ingresarSim);
$reg->bind_param("i", $ingresarSim);
```

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, viendo ambos estilos para mysqli si que es mejor el orientado a objetos

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, el programa no tiene errores pero una pequeña pregunta.

El programa consiste en que debe borrar los datos de un registro una vez sean iguales a la de otro registro, O sea introducir el dato de "B" pero si "B" en un futuro es introducido en otra base de datos pues se debe borrar de la primera base de datos.

En selec tengo la variable ingresar que es donde entrar el primer valor pero en delete tambien tengo la variable ingresar, deberia poner la variable de lo que entre en la segunda base de datos?

Comment: @A.Cedano Me dice que no se encontraron filas pero no entiendo porque me dice eso si en la parte de seleccionar las filas puse  FROM ventas que es el nombre de la tabla WHERE sim que es el nombre de la columna y aun asi dice que no encuentra filas

Comment: @NathanaelDeLeon si es como dices debes usar el valor que identifique el registro de manera única como criterio (en el `WHERE` de la instrucción `DELETE`), supongo que esa columna es `SIM`. Esto se podría hacer también a nivel de base de datos, programando un disparador (`TRIGGER`) que se lanzaría después de insertar borrando el registro en la otra tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Propongo lo siguiente:

- Has un conteo en tu consulta `SELECT` para que de este modo sepas si existe al menos 1 fila coincidente por el id pasado
- La variable donde almacenes el resultado de la consulta la evaluarás como un valor numérico para indicar que si es mayor a 0 entonces existen registros y proceda la eliminación, en caso contrario no elimina nada
- Aclaremos que tu quieres verificar el número de filas que en tu tabla existen con ese id entonces el usar `mysqli_fetch_array` no hace sentido pues este devuelve el conjunto de resultados como un array asociativo o numérico
- Del mismo modo si queremos la referencia número a de las filas que existen tomando el `sim` no hace sentido solicitar el `id` puesto que no será un valor empleable
- Por cierto nuevamente en el `DELETE` estás pasando un valor directo, aquí nuevamente debes usar sentencias preparadas

Código:

```
mysqli_select_db($conexv,$db) or die("problemas base de datos");

$reg = mysqli_prepare($conexv, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ventas WHERE sim = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($reg, "i", $ingresarSim);
mysqli_stmt_execute($reg);

$conteoFilas = mysqli_stmt_get_result($reg);

if (!$reg) {
    print_r(mysqli_error($conexv));
} else {
    if ($conteoFilas->field_count > 0) {
        $eliminado = mysqli_query($conexv, "DELETE FROM sim WHERE SIM = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($eliminado, "i", $ingresarSim);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($eliminado);
        echo "Datos Eliminados";
    } else {
        echo "Datos no han sido Eliminados";
    }
}
```

**Referencias**

- [manejo de errores en mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)
- [mysqli_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)
- [añado el uso de mysqli_stmt_get_results](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

Comment: Otro error mas, en serio perdon por molestarte

mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in

Dice linea 21, esta: if (mysqli_num_rows($reg) > 0) {

Comment: Ya borre los comentarios, solo deje el ultimo

Comment: Esta bien, espero

Comment: Ahora aparecen dos errores:
mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in
//////////////mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in

En estas dos lineas:
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($eliminado, "i", $ingresarSim);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($eliminado);

Comment: Me gustaria mandarte el codigo completo para que lo revises pero no quiero molestarte

Comment: Hay algunas cosas en tu código: 1) Es mejor usar [`mysqli_stmt_bind_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) en vez de `mysqli_stmt_get_result` ya que éste último sólo está presente si está instalado el driver `mysqlnd`; 2) El bloque `if (!$reg) {` está mal implementado, deberías verificar eso antes de pasar a leer los datos; 3) No le veo sentido a esto: `if ($conteoFilas->field_count > 0) {`, lo que deberías verificar es **el conteo de filas que arrojó el `SELECT`, no el conteo de columnas**, si te arroja `0` filas como `N` filas, `field_count` será siempre `1`.

Comment: El aporte está bien, hice el comentario con la idea de que lo mejores y sea una eventual respuesta aceptada.